# Get attribute value by using XSLT function

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking for XSLT function to get attribute value from XML file. The format of xml file is below,

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<collection id="b1" title="Employers and Employees" filename="Y:\Content\test.nfo" password="">

<field name="test" index="yes" phrase="no" stop-words="yes" term-list="no" proximity="yes"/> 
<field name="form" index="yes" phrase="no" stop-words="yes" term-list="no" proximity="yes"/>
<field name="stat" index="yes" phrase="no" stop-words="yes" term-list="no" proximity="yes"/>
```

How I should I retrieve id and title value?

Thanks.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. You are not showing well-formed XML, use the term "XSLT function" but most likely mean something else, you do not show any XSLT code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a valid XML file, it has to start and end with the same entity. In your case it has to end with a closing `</collection>`.
As you're referring to XSLT, following template retrieves both values (when the closing collection-tag is added):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="/collection/@id"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="/collection/@title"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>b1Employers and Employees`

As it's unclear how you want to proceed with the retrieved values and just wanted to know how to retrieve them, just the XML output as example.

Answer (score 0):

From the current node:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
```